# EEException: Unable to use a collection in an algorithm that requires a feature or image

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

```
EEException: Unable to use a collection in an algorithm that requires a feature or image. This may happen when trying to use a collection of collections where a collection of features is expected; use flatten, or map a function to convert inner collections to features. Use clipToCollection (instead of clip) to clip an image to a collection.
```

Code:

```py
# Landsat 9 Data
dataSet = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2") \
    .filterDate('2023-01-01', '2023-05-30') \
    .filterBounds(roi) \
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 10)

# Scaling Factors
def applyScaleFactors(image):
    opticalBands = image.select(['SR_B1', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7']) \
                        .multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2)
    thermalBands = image.select(['ST_B10']) \
                        .multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0)
    return image.addBands(opticalBands, None, True).addBands(thermalBands, None, True)

rescale = dataSet.map(applyScaleFactors)
image = rescale.median()

# Train
label = 'Class'
bands = ['SR_B1', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7']
input = image.select(bands)

trainImage = input.sampleRegions(**{
    'collection': training,  # Make sure 'training' is a feature collection
    'properties': [label],
    'scale': 20
})

trainingData = trainImage.randomColumn()
trainSet = trainingData.filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('random', 0.8))
testSet = trainingData.filter(ee.Filter.greaterThan('random', 0.8))

# Classification Model
classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10) \
    .train(features=trainSet,
           classProperty=label,
           inputProperties=bands)

classify = input.classify(classifier)

# Classification Colors
palette = [
    '#0c2c84',  # water
    '#e31a1c',  # urban
    '#005a32',  # forest
    '#FF8000',  # crop
    '#969696'   # barren
]
# Add the classified image to the map
m.addLayer(classify, {'palette': palette, 'min': 1, 'max': 5}, 'Classification')

# Assess Accuracy
confusionMatrix = ee.ConfusionMatrix(testSet.classify(classifier) \
    .errorMatrix({
        'actual': 'Class',
        'predicted': 'classification'
    }))

print('Confusion Matrix: ', confusionMatrix)
print('Overall Accuracy: ', confusionMatrix.accuracy())
print('Producers Accuracy: ', confusionMatrix.producersAccuracy())
print('Consumers Accuracy: ', confusionMatrix.consumersAccuracy())
```